# numpy - einsum notation: dot product of a stack of matrices with stack of vectors

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to multiply an n-dim stack of m* m matrices by an n-dim stack of vectors (length m), so that the resulting m*n array contains the result of the dot product of the matrix and vector in the nth entry:

```
vec1=np.array([0,0.5,1,0.5]); vec2=np.array([2,0.5,1,0.5])
vec=np.transpose(n.stack((vec1,vec2)))
mat = np.moveaxis(n.array([[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]],[[-1,2.,0,1.],[0,0,-1,2.],[0,1,-1,2.],[1,0.1,1,1]]]),0,2)
outvec=np.zeros((4,2))
for i in range(2):
    outvec[:,i]=np.dot(mat[:,:,i],vec[:,i])
```

Inspired by this post [Element wise dot product of matrices and vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415207/element-wise-dot-product-of-matrices-and-vectors), I have tried all different perturbations of index combinations in einsum, and have found that

```
np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik',mat,vec)
```

gives the correct result.

Unfortunately I really do not understand this - I assumed the fact that I repeat the entry k in the 'ijk,jk' part means that I multiply AND sum over k. I've tried to read the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html, but I still don't understand.

(My previous attempts included,

```
 np.einsum('ijk,il->ik', mat, vec)
```

I'm not even sure what this means. What happens to the index l when I drop it?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read about **understanding numpy einsum** here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [321]: vec1=np.array([0,0.5,1,0.5]); vec2=np.array([2,0.5,1,0.5])
     ...: vec=np.transpose(np.stack((vec1,vec2)))
In [322]: vec1.shape
Out[322]: (4,)
In [323]: vec.shape
Out[323]: (4, 2)
```

A nice thing about the `stack` function is we can specify an axis, skipping the transpose:

```
In [324]: np.stack((vec1,vec2), axis=1).shape
Out[324]: (4, 2)
```

Why the mix of `np.` and `n.`? `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`.  That kind of thing almost sends me away.

```
In [326]: mat = np.moveaxis(np.array([[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]],[[-1,2.,0
     ...: ,1.],[0,0,-1,2.],[0,1,-1,2.],[1,0.1,1,1]]]),0,2)
In [327]: mat.shape
Out[327]: (4, 4, 2)

In [328]: outvec=np.zeros((4,2))
     ...: for i in range(2):
     ...:     outvec[:,i]=np.dot(mat[:,:,i],vec[:,i])
     ...:     
In [329]: outvec
Out[329]: 
array([[ 4.  , -0.5 ],
       [ 4.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 4.  ,  0.5 ],
       [ 4.  ,  3.55]])

In [330]: # (4,4,2) (4,2)   'kji,ji->ki'
```

From your loop, the location of the `i` axis (size 2) is clear - last in all 3 arrays.  That leaves one axis for `vec`, lets call that `j`.  It pairs with the last (next to `i` of `mat`). `k` carries over from `mat` to `outvec`.

```
In [331]: np.einsum('kji,ji->ki', mat, vec)
Out[331]: 
array([[ 4.  , -0.5 ],
       [ 4.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 4.  ,  0.5 ],
       [ 4.  ,  3.55]])
```

Often the `einsum` string writes itself.  For example if `mat` was described as (m,n,k) and `vec` as (n,k), with the result being (m,k)

In this case only the `j` dimension is summed - it appears on the left, but on the right.  The last dimension, `i` in my notation, is not summed because if appears on both sides, just as it does in your iteration.  I think of that as 'going-along-for-the-ride'.  It isn't actively part of the `dot` product.

You are, in effect, stacking on the last dimension, size 2 one.  Usually we stack on the first, but you transpose both to put that last.

---

Your 'failed' attempt runs, and can be reproduced as:

```
In [332]: np.einsum('ijk,il->ik', mat, vec)
Out[332]: 
array([[12. ,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  1. ],
       [12. ,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  3.1]])
In [333]: mat.sum(axis=1)*vec.sum(axis=1)[:,None]
Out[333]: 
array([[12. ,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  1. ],
       [12. ,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  3.1]])
```

The `j` and `l` dimensions don't appear on the right, so they are summed.  They can be summed before multiplying because they appear in only one term each.  I added the `None` to enable broadcasting (multiplying a `ik` with `i`).

```
np.einsum('ik,i->ik', mat.sum(axis=1), vec.sum(axis=1))
```

---

If you'd stacked on the first, and added a dimension for `vec` (2,4,1), it would `matmul` with a (2,4,4) mat.   `mat @ vec[...,None]`.

```
In [337]: m1 = mat.transpose(2,0,1)
In [338]: m1@v1[...,None]
Out[338]: 
array([[[ 4.  ],
        [ 4.  ],
        [ 4.  ],
        [ 4.  ]],

       [[-0.5 ],
        [ 0.  ],
        [ 0.5 ],
        [ 3.55]]])
In [339]: _.shape
Out[339]: (2, 4, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I went back and forth but eventually decided to accept the other one as the answer because I thought it'd be more helpful to have a cheat sheet for the einsum summation. But your explanation was super helpful, especially the discussion of the None axis explicitly and the rephrasing of einsum with other commands! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Basically, the rules are:

## Without a `->`

- Any letter repeated in the inputs represents an axis to be multipled and summed over
- Any letter not repeated in the inputs is included in the output

## With a `->`

- Any letter repeated in the inputs represents an axis to be multipled over
- Any letter not in the output represents an axis to be summed over

So, for example, with matrices `A` and `B` wih same shape:

```
np.einsum('ij, ij',       A, B)  # is A ddot B,                returns 0d scalar
np.einsum('ij, jk',       A, B)  # is A dot  B,                returns 2d tensor
np.einsum('ij, kl',       A, B)  # is outer(A, B),             returns 4d tensor
np.einsum('ji, jk, kl',   A, B)  # is A.T @ B @ A,             returns 2d tensor
np.einsum('ij, ij -> ij', A, B)  # is A * B,                   returns 2d tensor
np.einsum('ij, ij -> i' , A, A)  # is norm(A, axis = 1),       returns 1d tensor
np.einsum('ii'             , A)  # is tr(A),                   returns 0d scalar
```

Answer (score 1):

`einsum` is easy (when you had played with permutation of indices for a while, that is...).

Let's work with something simple, a triple stack of *2×2* matrices and a triple stack of *2×,* arrays

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3*2*2).reshape((3,2,2))
b = np.arange(3*2).reshape((3,2))
```

We need to know what we are going to compute using `einsum`

```
In [101]: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     print(a[i]@b[i])                                                                            
[1 3]
[23 33]
[77 95]
```

What we have done? we have an index `i` that is fixed when we perform a dot product between one of the stacked matrices and one of the stacked vectors (both indexed by `i`) and the individual output line implies a summation over the last index of the stacked matrix and the lone index of the stacked vector.

This is easily encoded in an `einsum` directive

- we want the same `i` index to specify the matrix, the vector and also the output,
- we want to reduce along the last matrix index and the remaining vector index, say `k`
- we want to have as many columns in the output as the rows in each stacked matrix, say `j`

Hence

```
In [102]: np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', a, b)                                                                   
Out[102]: 
array([[ 1,  3],
       [23, 33],
       [77, 95]])
```

I hope that my discussion of how I got the directive right is clear, correct and useful.