# Vectorizing multidimensional matrix products with numpy (einsum)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I would like to perform a series of rotations with mxm arrays on a series nxm matrices in a vectorized fashion (1000xmxm dot 1000xnxm --> 1000xnxm).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731784/numpy-einsum-notation-dot-product-of-a-stack-of-matrices-with-stack-of-vector) seems to have the answer if my nxm matrices were 1xm vectors, but unfortunately they are not.  I was wondering if there is an einsum that I could use, or some other matrix manipulation to not have to loop over 1000 times.

Comment: Where does the `13`  come from?  In a `dot` one pair of dimensions is summed?  Which is in your case.  With several sets of `3` it's ambiguous.  The default behavior for `dot` and `matmul` is last dimension of `A` with the 2nd to the last of `B`.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have edited for clarity both the title and the notation to make this less ambiguous.

Comment: Just swap the factors? `M1000nm@M1000mm`?

Comment: 'kij,kni->knj' or 'kij,knj->kni', summing either on the `i` or the `j`

Comment: @hpaulj That worked within a transpose, thanks so much!

Comment: You can change the order of dimensions on the output, 'knj` to 'kjn'  or whatever works.